# Does the Empire have Active fire protection on its ships / Space stations?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

There are lots of scenes where things are blown up or catch on fire within a spaceship or even the Death-Star. ie, a Star Destroyer plunging head first into it creating massive damage to the space station.

However when Kylo-Ren destroys his panel in a fit of rage, the panel is on fire but nothing happens:

Is there some kind of system that will not allow a fire to get out of hand on a space ship?

Comment: Panicked interns wielding fire extinguishers enter the room after the scene ends and spray maniacally, mostly hitting Kylo Ren instead of the control panel.

Comment: @Skooba, when you find out how any of this works, let me know. B/c I still don't???

Answer (score 3):

**This scene does not offer much evidence of fire protection.**

The computer panels that Kylo Ren destroyed mostly do *not* seem to be on fire.

[image]

There’s a bunch of molten metal, and one or two small, localized flames (particularly in the upper left). Presumably a few of the smaller computer components are slightly flammable.

The novelization simply mentions “bleeding metal”:

> Ren was slashing at the console nearby, at the walls, at the deck,
> rending and ripping, slashing long lines of bleeding metal into the
> very fabric of the ship.
>
> <sub>*The Force Awakens*</sub>

Similarly, the [script](https://www.scribd.com/doc/294421853/Star-Wars-Force-Awakens-Final-Script) simply refers to "glowing scars":

> The metallic wall behind Ren  is RIPPED with glowing scars.

On the whole, this is consistent with what we’ve seen before when a lightsaber is used on metal:

[image]

**In essence, the fire doesn’t spread because there wasn’t much of a fire to begin with. The computer is not particularly flammable.** Besides, it’s probably surrounded by metal.

The incidents that cause fires tend to be **much more violent and energetic, affecting much larger areas of the ship—areas that could have various flammable or explosive components.**

---

I don’t know of any evidence for automated fire protection in canon (though there may be some). However, in Legends, various ships have automated [extinguisher foam](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Extinguisher_foam):

> Flames bathed the corridor in orange. The Massassi’s screams were lost
> in the explosion and the shock wave rattled Relin’s teeth. Alarms
> shrieked, and fire foam hissed out of valves in the ceiling.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Crosscurrent*</sub>

It’s entirely possible (indeed, even likely) that something similar exists for fires in canon. Of course, it won’t be enough to deal with *any* fire, but it could certainly contain small ones.

Answer (score 2):

**Sentinel Base** (the staging area for the Death Star) has fire-suppression systems, presumably based on foam.

> *Originally a cramped garrison base deployed from a Victory-class Star
> Destroyer, Sentinel now sprawled in all directions as a result of
> prefabricated modules that had since been delivered or assembled on
> site. The heart of the facility was a warren of corridors linking one
> module to the next, their ceilings lost behind banks of harsh
> illuminators, forced-air ducts, **fire-suppression pipes,** and bundled
> strands of snaking wires.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))</sup></sub>

**The Star Destroyer Vigilance** has *fire-suppressing droids* swarming around.

> *Sloane stands amid the smoldering wreckage of the long-range fighter.
> It stinks of ozone and fire. A pair of gleaming black astromechs whir,
> firing extinguishing foam to put out the last of the flames. They have
> to navigate around the half dozen or so stormtrooper bodies that lie
> about, still. Helmets cracked. Chest plates charred. Blaster rifles
> scattered and broken.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Aftermath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath)</sup></sub>